# Set timeout for different targets in AWS Application load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

There is an Application Load Balancer (ALB) with a HTTP listener.
There are 3 target groups TG1, TG2, TG3

In the HTTP listener, there are rules:

```
- path /foo --> TG1
- path /bar --> TG2
- default   --> TG3
```

ALB has a default idle timeout of 60 seconds to all incoming requests. How to set different timeouts at listener level, for example, 30 seconds for `/foo` and 40 seconds for `/bar`?

Comment: Its not possible.

Comment: What could be the best workaround?